# Can I create a map using leaflet js to view area codes of cities in the United States?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Leaflet sample</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 580px"></div>
  <script>
    // Creating map options
    var mapOptions = {
      center: [39.0997, 94.5786],
      zoom: 4
    }

    // Creating a map object
    var map = new L.map('map', mapOptions);

    // Creating a Layer object
    var layer = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');

    // Adding layer to the map
    map.addLayer(layer);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably? I'm not sure. Have you looked into any solutions yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The US area code map is already here:

https://www.allareacodes.com/area-code-map.htm

I think you need to develop something like this:

https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

which is the choropleth map. In the link above, you can find the way how to do it.
Te first hand example applies to the population density. You can change it towards postcodes, since you have the state boundaries ready ([this link](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/us-states.js)).

The key thing here is:

```
 function getColor(d) {
   return d &gt; 1000 ? '#800026' :
       d &gt; 500  ? '#BD0026' :
       d &gt; 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
       d &gt; 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
       d &gt; 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
       d &gt; 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
       d &gt; 10   ? '#FED976' :
                  '#FFEDA0';
  }
```

and

```
 function style(feature) {
     return {
      fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density),
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 1,
      color: 'white',
      dashArray: '3',
      fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
   }

   L.geoJson(statesData, {style: style}).addTo(map);
```

and finally the highlighting option

```
 function highlightFeature(e) {
var layer = e.target;

 layer.setStyle({
    weight: 5,
    color: '#666',
    dashArray: '',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
  });

   if (!L.Browser.ie &amp;&amp; !L.Browser.opera &amp;&amp; !L.Browser.edge) {
    layer.bringToFront();
 }
 }
```